# Database or API of icao24 (aircraft ID) information

Tags: data-request, aviation

Is anyone aware of a database, API, or other source of data on [icao24](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation_transponder_interrogation_modes)?

I want to be able to give an icao24 (from an [OpenSky API](https://opensky-network.org/apidoc/rest.html#all-state-vectors)), and get some information as much information as possible about the associated aircraft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do have an aircraft database available right on the website (also for download): https://opensky-network.org/aircraft-database

Otherwise, the usual suspects are there for individual research but no API: https://flightradar24.com/data, FlightAware, Radarbox etc.

Answer (score 1):

These might be interesting for you:

1. http://www.airframes.org
2. https://www.flarmnet.org/flarmnet/